“Enable experimental support for pseudo consoles” without reinstalling Git?
When you install Git for Windows, there is an “Enable experimental support for pseudo consoles” checkbox.
How to check whether it is actually enabled after installation, and enable it if it is not? – without reinstalling Git

This is actually configured in /etc/git-bash.config. Either open the file from within git-bash (e.g. using vim), or locate it on your file system (C:\Program Files\Git\etc\git-bash.config).
You must simply set
MSYS=enable_pcon

Then it will be available in new git-bash instances.
(found here)
